# Fragment can not be displayed when navigation drawer item is selected

Tags: android, runnable, navigation-drawer

### MainActivity

---

Navigation drawer is open and close smoothly using **Runnable()** but fragment can not be displayed when drawer item is selected.

```
 public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(final int position,View view) {
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        switch (position) {

                            case 0:
                                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
                                break;

                            case 1:
                                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
//                        Intent i = new Intent(con, SplashScreenActivity.class);
//                        startActivity(i);
//                        finish();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(view);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform your operation in `runOnUiThread` only instead of calling runOnUiThread in `Runnable`. Your code should looks like :

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(final int position,View view) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    switch (position) {

                        case 0:
                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                             fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new   HomeFragment()).commit();
  //                        Intent i = new Intent(con, SplashScreenActivity.class);
   //                        startActivity(i);
    //                        finish();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });


    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(view);
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
```

Comment: i edit my code but navigation drawer in not automatically closed when i clicked on drawer item..it still remaining open. @Kapil Rajput